# Scroll the menu if expanded menu rows overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed side navigation menu with a menu item `Dropdown` that can expand/collapse additional rows.

If `Dropdown` is expanded when it's at the bottom of the container then I can't see the menu items without manually scrolling down:

[image]

How could make it expand `Dropdown` in that position and automatically scroll down (if needed) just enough to display all the child items?:

[image] [image]

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* Some media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#clients">MenuItem</a>
  <a href="#clients">MenuItem6</a>
      <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#contact">Search</a>
  <a href="#clients">MenuItem2</a>
  <a href="#clients">MenuItem9</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu inside the side navigation.</p>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Some random text..</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment;

[`this.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end' })`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on **the last child** should do the trick!

`{ block: 'end' }` defines vertical alignment so that it will scroll to the bottom of viewable element

---

Second comment;

By comparing the bottom of the last child with the visible part of the scrollable element, we can determine if the row is visible and decide to scroll.

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var sidenav = document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")[0];

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {  
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
   
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  
  // Get last-child bottom
  const lastChild = dropdownContent.children[dropdownContent.children.length - 1];
  const lastChildRect = lastChild.getBoundingClientRect();
  const lastChildBottom = lastChildRect.bottom;
  
  // Get height off scrollable element
  const sidenavHeight = sidenav.clientHeight;
  
  // If visible
  if (lastChildBottom > sidenavHeight) {
      
      // Scroll into view
      console.log('Scroll');
      lastChild.scrollIntoView({block: "end"});
  }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* Some media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#clients">MenuItem</a>
  <a href="#clients">MenuItem6</a>
      <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#contact">Search</a>
  <a href="#clients">MenuItem2</a>
  <a href="#clients">MenuItem9</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu inside the side navigation.</p>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Some random text..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is really close to what I need! I would need it to scroll down _just_ enough to bring the child items into full view. This means that `Dropdown` would not necessarily go all the way to the top. The parent items below `Dropdown` would also not be visible, just like in the third photo of my post.

Comment: 0stone0, thank you so much. Just one more thing I'd like to ask. If you scroll down to the bottom on that menu and press `Dropdown`, as you've mentioned the menu scrolls down to the last child. However, `Dropdown` was high enough to display the children below without it needing to scroll down. Is it possible to scroll down only when it's needed? I hope that's clear.